# VS2010 Create installer with multiple directories

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, installation

I have been looking for ages and I can't find any good examples of how to edit the standard installer for visual studio 2010. I need to create an installer that allows the user to specify 3 folder directories to install files into. Once the 3 folders are specified and the files are installed I need to write the directory locations in to an INI file.

Any tips or tutorial links would be great thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported by Visual Studio. It can be done only with other setup authoring tools.

If you want a free solution, you can try [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/). It has a steep learning curve, but it gets the job done.

Comment: Ok Thanks, I'll look into the them other options.